# Generating dynamic validate set based on value of another parameter in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, dynamicparameters

A little background: We are working on a function that goes through hundreds of entries, similar to the following:

| City | State | Population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| New York | New York | 8467513 |
| Los Angeles | California | 3849297 |
| Chicago | Illinois | 2696555 |
| Houston | Texas | 2288250 |
| Phoenix | Arizona | 1624569 |
| Philadelphia | Pennsylvania | 1576251 |
| San Antonio | Texas | 1451853 |
| San Diego | California | 1381611 |
| Dallas | Texas | 1288457 |
| San Jose | California | 983489 |

The raw data will be gotten using an `Import-Csv`. The CSV is updated on a regular basis.

We are trying to use PowerShell classes to enable people to select the `City` based on the `State` they select. Here is the MWE we have gotten so far:

```
$Global:StateData = Import-Csv \\path\to\city-state-population.csv

class State : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator {
    [string[]] GetValidValues() {
        return (($Global:StateData).State | Select-Object -Unique)
    }
}
class City : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator {
    [string[]] GetValidValues($State) {
        return ($Global:StateData | Where-Object State -eq $State).City
    }
}
function Get-Population {
    param (
        # Name of the state
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
        [ValidateSet([State])]
        $State,

        # Name of the city
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 1)]
        [ValidateSet([City])]
        $City
    )
    
    $City | ForEach-Object {
        $TargetCity = $City | Where-Object City -match $PSItem
        "The population of $($TargetCity.City), $($TargetCity.State) is $($TargetCity.Population)."
    }
}
```

Of course, according to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.ivalidatesetvaluesgenerator.getvalidvalues?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#system-management-automation-ivalidatesetvaluesgenerator-getvalidvalues=), `GetValidValues()` does not seem to accept parameter input. Is there a way to achieve this at all?

The results would need to be similar to [PowerShell Function – Validating a Parameter Depending On A Previous Parameter’s Value](https://sqldbawithabeard.com/2017/04/26/powershell-function-validating-a-parameter-depending-on-a-previous-parameter/), but the approach the post takes is beyond imagination for the amount of data we have.

**Note**: This is on PowerShell (Core), and not Windows PowerShell. The latter does not have the `IValidateSetValuesGenerator` interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm honestly not sure if you can do this with two [`ValidateSet` Attribute Declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/validateset-attribute-declaration?view=powershell-7.2), however, you could make it work with one `ValidateSet` and a [custom class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes) that implements the [`IArgumentCompleter` Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.iargumentcompleter?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) since it has access to **[`$fakeBoundParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_argument_completion?view=powershell-7.2#argumentcompleter-script-block)**. Here is an example, that for sure needs refinement but hopefully can get you on track.

```bash
using namespace System.Management.Automation
using namespace System.Management.Automation.Language
using namespace System.Collections
using namespace System.Collections.Generic

class State : IValidateSetValuesGenerator {
    [string[]] GetValidValues() {
        return $script:StateData.State | Select-Object -Unique
    }
}

class Completer : IArgumentCompleter {
    [IEnumerable[CompletionResult]] CompleteArgument(
        [string] $CommandName,
        [string] $ParameterName,
        [string] $WordToComplete,
        [CommandAst] $CommandAst,
        [IDictionary] $FakeBoundParameters
    ) {
        [List[CompletionResult]] $result = foreach($line in $script:StateData) {
            if($line.State -ne $FakeBoundParameters['State'] -or $line.City -notlike "*$wordToComplete*") {
                continue
            }
            $city = $line.City
            [CompletionResult]::new("'$city'", $city, [CompletionResultType]::ParameterValue, $city)
        }
        return $result
    }
}

function Get-Population {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
        [ValidateSet([State])]
        [string] $State,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 1)]
        [ArgumentCompleter([Completer])]
        [string] $City
    )

    "State: $State \\ City: $City"
}
```

**Demo**

[image: demo]

Comment: Works exactly as intended in the question, in PowerShell (Core). Those using PowerShell 5.1 should note that the `IValidateSetValuesGenerator` interface isn't available on Windows PowerShell.

Comment: @RamIyer I just assumed you were using PowerShell Core because of the `IValidateSetValuesGenerator` implementation :)

Comment: I understand. This ran on my dev machine, but not on one of our servers, which is when I noticed this. I added the comment just to ensure those using legacy PowerShell are aware of it. On retrospect, that note should be on my question instead. Edited it. :)

Answer (score 3):

I like to use the `Register-ArgumentCompleter` cmdlet for that kind of things. If you are looking just for argument completion, then it will work perfectly. You'll have to do validation yourself within the function though as it won't prevent incorrect entry to be typed in.

It will however, provide a list of possible argument and the cities displayed will be only the cities associated to the State chosen.

Here's an example.

```
$Data = @'
City|State|Population
New York|New York|8467513
Los Angeles|California|3849297
Chicago|Illinois|2696555
Houston|Texas|2288250
Phoenix|Arizona|1624569
Philadelphia|Pennsylvania|1576251
San Antonio|Texas|1451853
San Diego|California|1381611
Dallas|Texas|1288457
San Jose|California|983489
'@| ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|'


Function Get-Population {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        $State, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        $City
    )
    return $Data | Where-Object { $_.State -eq $State -and $_.City -eq $City } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Population 

} 

$PopulationArgCompletion = {
    param($commandName, $parameterName, $wordToComplete, $commandAst, $fakeBoundParameters)

    

    Filter CompleteWordExpand($Property) { if ($_.$Property -like "*$wordToComplete*") { return $_.$Property } }
    

    $ReturnData = $null

    switch ($ParameterName) {
        'State' { 
            $ReturnData = $Data | CompleteWordExpand -Property State  
        }
        'City' {
            if ($fakeBoundParameters.ContainsKey('State')) {
                $ReturnData = $Data |  Where-Object -Property State -eq $fakeBoundParameters.Item('State') | CompleteWordExpand -Property City 
            }
        }
        else {
            $ReturnData = $Data | CompleteWordExpand -Property City 
        }

    }

    if ($null -ne $ReturnData) {
        return $ReturnData | Select -Unique | ForEach-Object {
            $ctText = [System.Management.Automation.CompletionResultType]::Text
            $CompletionText = $_
            if ($_.indexof(" ") -gt -1) { $CompletionText = "'$_'" }
            [System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult]::new($CompletionText, $_, $ctText, $_)
        }
    }

}


Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName Get-Population -ParameterName State -ScriptBlock $PopulationArgCompletion
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName Get-Population -ParameterName City -ScriptBlock $PopulationArgCompletion
```

**Additional note**

If you do test this, make sure to try it out in a different file than where you executed the script above. For some reason, VSCode and/or the PS extension do not show the argument completion if you try to do your testing (eg: Calling `Get-Population` to see the argument completion) in the same file you ran the script above.

**Additional additional note**

I edited my answer to include a `CompleteWord` filter that make it work properly with console tab completion, which was ommited from my initial answer. Since this is not really an in the code editor and I mostly never use the console directly, I had never took that into consideration.

Also, I added an additional check so that any state or cities that are multiple words get automatically surrounded by single quotes during the tab completion to avoid issues.

**Bonus VSCode Snippet**

Here is the snippet I use to generate quickly a template for the basis of doing argument completion everywhere when needed.

```
    "ArgumentCompletion": {
        "prefix": "ArgComplete",
        "body": [
            "$${1:MyArgumentCompletion} = {",
            "    param(\\$commandName, \\$parameterName, \\$wordToComplete, \\$commandAst, \\$fakeBoundParameters)",
            "",
            "      # [System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult]::new(\\$_)",
            "}",
            "",
            "Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName ${2:Command-Name} -ParameterName ${3:Name} -ScriptBlock $${1:MyArgumentCompletion}"
        ]
    }
```

**References**

[Register-ArgumentCompleter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/register-argumentcompleter?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: Works, thank you for this! Tab completion not working is a little caveat that might hinder the use of this in _my particular use case_, given the hundreds of possibilities of the "State" attribute of this example in my implementation. Although, not having to create a custom class makes it easier for non-.NET folks to implement this.

Comment: @RamIyer Tab completion do work though. The caveat is that if you work in vscode, have 1 file open (let's say "tmp.ps1"), paste my code and execute it, tab completion will work everywhere except within the "tmp.ps1" file. So you just need to make sure that the code that register the argument completer and where you want to use it is the same file. This is really an edge case and only a thing that might happen if you wanted to test it quickly but in any other situation, it would likely be imported from a file and / or module so it would never be an issue really.

Comment: (It is really an oddball case but since I work a lot with argument completers and I have a tendancy to work from a single file during my testing phase, I noticed that behavior).

Comment: Okay, noted, thank you! In fact, I'm struggling with implementing this across multiple cmdlets. If you could share the link to a sample of how you do it, it would be great. If this is not the place to ask for it, my apologies.

Comment: @RamIyer My answer demonstrate how I'd use it but you can see one implementation I used for my module SecretManagementArgumentCompleter [here](https://github.com/itfranck/SecretManagementArgumentCompleter/blob/aa1691833ac51e4e96a575b2f646bc7fae6bbed1/Output/SecretManagementArgumentCompleter/SecretManagementArgumentCompleter.psm1#L236). Also, since long chain or comments that deviate from the answer are discourage, here is a link to a [SO chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246035/powershell-argument-completer)  I created  if you have questions

Comment: @RamIyer Based on our chat interaction, I updated my answer to  fix the issue you were describing. See the updated code along with the additional additional note.